# How to disable autosave in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have very slow upload speeds and upload also interferes with my download so I need to disable autosave in Colab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the notebook in playground mode using Tools -> Command pallet menu.
[image]

Playground mode disables saves. In order to save manually, you'll need to create a copy of the notebook using the menu File -> Save a copy in Drive.

Comment: This is really the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: Presently, yes.

Answer (score 1):

if you go to `Runtime > Change runtime type` there is an option called `Omit code cell output when saving this notebook` with this option enabled you have private outputs and your Outputs will not be saved.