# Google colab consumes too much of internet data

Tags: google-colaboratory

Recently google colab consumes too much of internet data . Approx 4GB in 6 hours of training for single notebook . What can be the issue ?

Comment: I have the same issue.Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 6):

Yes I have the same issue. It normally works fine but, there is sudden spike in the internet data. [Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms9QI.png). In the process it wasted 700 Mb in just 20 minutes, and I have mobile internet, so this creates a problem sometimes. Didn't find the answer but it seems like there is some kind of synchronization going on between the browser and the colab platform.

One thing you could do is to open the notebook in Playground mode as shown in this link [How to remove the autosave option in Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207750/how-to-disable-autosave-in-google-colab). This only happens because of the fact that Colab is saving everytime and there is a constant spike in the network. It becomes difficult when you use only mobile data. So, it is a safe option to open the notebook in Playground mode, so that the synchronization doesn't continue as usual.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue in 2023 ? Did google make some improvements in the bandwidth usage during the editing process ?

Comment: I don't think this problem persists... Anyways, colab has reduced the run-time; hence not using it much now...