# Why Colab stops training and the browser becomes unresponsive?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a model for image recognition using Yolo version 3 with this notebook:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YnZLp6aIl-iSrL4tzVQgxJaE1N2_GfFH/view?usp=sharing

But for some reason, everything works fine but the final training. The training starts, and after 5-10 minutes (randomly) it stops working. The browser becomes unresponsive (I am unable to do anything inside that tab), and after several minutes Colab completely disconnects.

I have tried this 10 and more times and I always get the same result. I tried it on both Chrome Canary and regular Chrome (last versions), as well inside anonymous windows, but I always get the same result.

Any ideas? Why is that happening?

Eager to know your thoughts about this.

All the best,

Fab.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. Tried the same process on Firefox and discovered that the auto-saving feature of Google drive was conflicting with the process! So... I had to simply use the "playground" of colab instead as explained here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207750/how-to-disable-autosave-in-google-colab#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=Open%20the%20notebook%20in%20playground,Save%20a%20copy%20in%20Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207750/how-to-disable-autosave-in-google-colab#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=Open%20the%20notebook%20in%20playground,Save%20a%20copy%20in%20Drive).

No idea why Chrome didn't give me any feedback about that, but Firefox saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Following @fabrizio-ferrari answer, I disabled output saving and the problem persisted.

`Runtime -> Change runtime type -> Omit code cell output when saving this notebook`

I moved to firefox and the problem disappeared.